# HTML/CSS - Side By Side Tables resize incorrectly

Tags: html, css

For an email report, I have created an HTML template. This template is filled with 6 Pandas Dataframes using Jinja2.

So, my HTML is composed by 6 tables in total. I want to show these tables as 3 rows x 2 tables each. For each row the tables should appear side-by-side.

The issue me and other recipients are having is that when we try to reply to this kind of email (using Outlook), the formatting of the email changes dramatically and (i) the columns layout doesn't exist anymore and the tables are showed one under the other and (ii) each tables resizes automatically fitting the whole width.

Furthermore, some recipients experiment this issue not only when they reply to this email but also when they receive the report.

I suspect something is wrong with my style properties and `display:flex` (I'm completely new to this).

How can I keep the tables side-by-side in every condition (when sending the email and when reply/forwarding)?

#### HTML Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2 class="title">{{contacts_left_title}}</h2>
        {{Contacts_monthly_mp}}
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2 class="title">{{contacts_right_title}}</h2>
        {{Contacts_weekly_mp}}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        {{Contacts_monthly}}
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        {{Contacts_weekly}}
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        {{Contacts_monthly_2}}
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        {{Contacts_weekly_2}}
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Style applied

```
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Calibri;
      font-size: 12pt;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 11pt;
      padding-left: 12px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    .Table_Style {
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        margin: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    .Table_Style td, th {
        padding: 4px;
        border: 1px solid silver; 
    }
    
    .Table_Style thead th {
        background-color: #4682B4; 
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .Table_Style tbody th {
        width: 25%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .Table_Style tbody td {
        width: 19%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .Table_Style caption {
      font-size: 9pt;
      padding: 10px;
      font-style: bold;
      color: #666;
      text-align: right;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
      

    .row {
      display: flex;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .column {
      padding: auto;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 15px;
    }  
    
    .column ul{
      font-size: 8pt;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }  
    
    .column h4{
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }  

    .box, hr, .column, .row, .Table_Style, .Brand_Style {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

[Supposed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnvpp.png)

[What I get when I reply to the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X2SU.png)

Answer (score 0):

A quote from this [excellent article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding-html-emails/):

> **Lean on tables—and not just for data.**
>
> The single most important guideline for HTML emails is that CSS layout
> just doesn’t work. The major email clients either offer no support at
> all, or mangle it in a myriad of frustratingly different ways.
>
> Using CSS instead of tables was the battle cry of the web standards
> war, but coding HTML emails means raising the white flag and giving
> in. Unless you’re building an extremely simple email, or your whole
> audience is using a more modern email reading tool, it’s back to those
> all encompassing **table** tags.

So, if you insist on building a pretty HTML email, your code needs to use tables for its entire layout. In your case, probably nested tables.

I'd seriously consider a different solution, though. How about generating your report as an HTML file on a web server and emailing your recipients a link to it? Or generating your report as a PDF and attaching that to an email message?

Comment: Unfortunately these options have been already excluded by my customers. They want data directly in their inbox without having to visit external resources (HTML pages or PDF attached). They are used to receive Excel reports via mail and those maintain the layout.